# Ionic 3, firebase push notification custom sound not working

Tags: firebase, cordova, audio, push-notification, ionic3

I have tried to implement custom sound for push notification in ionic 3.
Everything works fine, like ,push notification icon, phone vibration. Only the custom sound not working, i have put it in - platform/android/res/raw, in mp3 format.
However, some of android version (like version 8) has the custom sound when push notification comes, but the other version (like 9,10) have no sound for push notification.  But the vibration works well.

Please help me how to do it for all android version as well as ios.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to give more detail if you want someone to help you, e.g. what Cordova plugin you are using for Firebase (and what version), how you are sending the notification message (e.g. FCM v1 API), an example message structure, etc.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late response. I'm using, 1) cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependency-updated. 2)and I'm trying to make a channel for receiving custom sound like that: this.fcm.createNotificationChannel({ id: myId, sound: mysound,  etc...})....3)my ionic version 6.6.0, cordova 8.1.0 , node version- 10.14.2.